# The stack pointer for stack 'CSTACK' is outside the stack range

Tags: c, debugging, ide, stack, iar

I am trying to execute some simple code on the IAR embedded workbench using a simulator. I've complied the code with no warnings or errors but during debugging I get this warning "The stack pointer for stack 'CSTACK' (currently 0x00000000) is outside the stack range (0x20000000 to 0x20001000)". My code fails to do even simple increment operations which I am finding really weird and hard to understand. I could find any proper solution for this problem Google or on IAR.
Any thoughts??

Comment: It sounds like you need to initialize your stack pointer.

Answer (score 2):

In `Options -> Linker -> Config -> Linker configuration file` you should have file that has a defines such as this:

> define symbol **ICFEDIT_region_RAM_start** = 0x20000000;
>   define symbol **ICFEDIT_size_cstack** = 0x1200;

In my project my file is named:

> STM32F2xx_FLASH.icf